# How to automatically divide eth in a wallet thats different from the smart contract address between nft holders?

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm trying to create a function in my contract that divides eth stored in a wallet among 100 holders. lets say there is 100eth within the contract, it sends 1 eth to a wallet address, and now this 1 eth is to be divided among 100 different holders.

How do i create a function that can access the 1eth and distribute it among the 100 holders?
please note that the second wallet will also be mine and i will have the private keys for it.

I'm not sure how to do this, i know how to distribute eth that already in the contract, but not outside the contract in another wallet. is this do-able? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No function on a smart contract can 'access' the eth that you have on an EOA (Externally Own Account) wallet, a regular wallet. A smart contract cannot access the eth in another account. The account voluntarily needs to send whatever amount to the contract, then, the contract can do whatever it wants with it since the eth would be already of it.

A regular account does not have any logic to do anything other than sending and receiving eth manually.

What you can do is to send that eth to another contract that will handle that for you.

Or receive the eth in the other EOA account and then send it to another contract that can do that.

Alternatively, you could create a decentralized contract that handles eth for addresses, and thus, do whatever it needs to do with the eth of those addresses.

For example, check the following simple DEX which handles user's ethers and does whatever logic it is supposed to do:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract DexEth {

    event Deposit(address from, uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp);
    event Withdraw(address to, uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp);
    event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount, uint256 timestamp);

    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Sender does not have enough eth to withdraw this amount");
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Error sending the eth to the sender.");
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, amount, block.timestamp);
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Sender does not have enough eth to transfer this amount");
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        (bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Error sending the eth to the recipient.");
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, amount, block.timestamp);
    }

    // Add whatever logic this contract is supposed to do

}
```

This is just an example. You can modify it and add/remove anything.